# Google Maps display KML data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-visualization, google-maps-markers

I have KML string and I want to display that on a Google Map.  Instead of a file, I have the string.  This is because I have my KML data inside the Fusion Tables, and I need to make something similar to this: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/custom_markers

I only have KML data, not coordinates, so I'm not sure how I would display that.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: '<polygon>....</polygon>',
      icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/images/fusion_tables-32.png')
 });
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these

[The geoxml3 project is an effort to develop a KML processor for use with Version 3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API, it now allows access to individual markers, polylines and polygons, rendered from KML.](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

[Some useful demos with KML](http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this line: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content

It answered my question!